# Can I configure a Samba AD with RFC2307 and join another Samba domain member with idmap RID backend?

Tags: server, 20.04, smb, active-directory, samba4

I have a Samba AD DC that I provisioned with --rfc2307.

I also have a separate Samba file server that is joined to this domain, and its smb.conf is configured with idmap_rid.

So far everything works fine, I can access the files and folder and set permissions and authenticate access to those folders with the Samba AD.

But re-reading the Samba documentation now it seems like I should be using idmap_ad for all Samba domain members, since the primary DC was configured with RFC2307. Though everything seemingly works fine now, I'm wondering if this might cause problems down the line.

Both servers are running on Ubuntu Server 20.04.

Comment: Adding '--use-rfc2307' to the provision command does three things, it adds a line to the DC's smb.conf, it adds an ldif that allowed the Unix attribute tab to work in ADUC and it makes the DC use any uidNumber & gidNumber attributes added to AD. So, the question is, have you added any uidNumber & gidNumber attributes to AD ? If not, then the winbind 'ad' backend will not work on your fileserver.

Comment: I haven't added any uidNumber & gidNumber attributes (the Unix attribute tab is no longer supported in Windows 10 anyway), which is why I thought I should just go with the RID backend. I'm just wondering if this (potential) mismatch between RFC2307 on the DC and RID on the fileserver is going to cause problems down the line.